# Step-by-step: Ward's method for calculating linkage

Tags: hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, ward

I'm trying to use Ward's method to calculate linkage for hierarchical agglomerative clustering with the data points below:
        $$a=(0,0)$$
        $$b=(1,2)$$
        $$c=(3,4)$$
        $$d=(4,1)$$
        $$e=(2,2)$$
According to some software, after joining b and e, the distance between a and {b,e} is 2.88, but I cannot see how this is derived?
Furthermore, I have not been able to find any step-by-step demonstration of calculating linkage using Ward's method online, if this could be explained would be very appreciated :)